# Visual Studio New Line Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm new to visual studio, so perhaps this is something easy... but I've had no luck finding how to solve this formatting issue.

I would like for VS to auto format this

```
int x = 
5;
```

like this

```
int x = 5;
```

When I type this in and select 'Format Document' nothing changes.

It will also not remove unnecessary newlines such as

```
MyClass someClass = 

    new MyClass();
```

Any help for this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio can't fix that. You can do it with the Replace All dialog + regex if you are careful.

Comment: Somewhat infuriating that VS can't do that, but at least good to know it wasn't my googling skills. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

jgauffin is right. However you can format other items to speed up the process.

[Tip for key combinations for general reformatting](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305195547/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/markhsch/archive/2008/01/10/visual-studio-tip-autoformat-your-code.aspx)

[Tip for using a macro to modify all files in your solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20170114083253/http://www.kodefuguru.com:80/post/Format-Solution.aspx)